# Expo multiple enviroments for react-native-firebase googleServicesFile

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase, eas

I have a problem that I don't know how to deal with. In my app (Expo SDK 48) i want to have a separate googleServicesFile source for each expo environment, i.e. for the dev environment I want a separate googleServicesFile for dev, and the same for test, uat and prod.

I tried to solve it, that in the eas.json file I have several configuration profiles for the development, uat, prod environment, and then in the app.config.js file, I check which profile is currently attached and on this basis assigns the appropriate path to googleServicesFile, but unfortunately regardless what profile will I run, the data is always saved on the development profile. Have any of you created multiple googleService configurations for Expo react native and would like to share how I can go about it?

```
eas.json

"build": {
  "development": {
     "distribution": "internal",
     "android": {
       "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
     },
     "env": {
       "APP_VARIANT": "stage"
     }
   },
  "uat": {
    ...,
    "env": {
       "APP_VARIANT": "uat"
     }
  }
```

```
app.config.js

"expo": {
  ...,
  "ios": {
    "googleServicesFile": process.env.APP_VARIANT === 'development' ? "./firebase/development/GoogleService-Info.plist" : "./firebase/uat/GoogleService-Info.plist",
  },
}
```

In addition, in the main project location I have a firebase folder where I store firebase files - GoogleService-Info-.plist for IOS and google-service.json for Android.

```
/firebase
  - development
    - GoogleService-Info.plist
    - google-service.json
  - uat
    - GoogleService-Info.plist
    - google-service.json
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? Stumbling across the same problem now

Comment: @bobski or DawidZacher did you guys figure the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To divide `Google Services files` by different development environments, you can add an `ios` object under the `expo` object in the `app.json` file and set the `Google ServicesFile` value differently for each development environment.

- Example

```json
{
  "expo": {
    // ...
  },
  "ios": {
    "googleServicesFile": {
      "dev": "./GoogleService-Info-dev.plist",
      "stage": "./GoogleService-Info-stage.plist",
      "production": "./GoogleService-Info-prod.plist"
    }
  }
}
```

When `dev` build

```bash
expo build:ios --no-publish --config app.dev.json
```

Comment: @DawidZacher If my answer helped you with your question, please check your answer and vote.

Comment: thank you for your answer but unfortunately the solution you provided is deprecated. Expo SDK 48 does not support the --config flag, additionally googleServicesFile cannot be an object, but a simple string path

Answer (score 0):

I created for each environment an `app.ENV_NAME.js` file, defining the `expo.ios.googleServicesFile` as needed.

In the main `app.config.js` file this is the content:

```
module.exports = () => {
    const config =
        process.env.APP_ENV === "production"
            ? require("./app.production.json")
            : process.env.APP_ENV === "staging"
            ? require("./app.staging.json")
            : process.env.APP_ENV === "development"
            ? require("./app.development.json")
            : require("./app.devcli.json");
     config.expo.version = "0.0.1";
     return config;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To change google services file used by your app you'll need to add env vars directly on `package.json`.

`eas.json` env vars are only used to provide in-app variables (e.g.: an backend api url).

`app.config.js` settings are used before `eas.json` is even readed.

So, in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev:ios|android": "VARIANT=dev ....",
  "stage:ios|android": "VARIANT=stage ....",
  "prod:ios|android": "VARIANT=prod ...."
}
```

Then in `app.config.js`:

```
const ambientSettings = (() => {
  const variant = process.env.VARIANT
  switch(variant) {
    case 'dev': return {
      servicesFile: 'path/to/dev/file',
      appName: 'My App (DEV)',
      package: 'dev.myapp'
    },
    case 'stage': return {
      servicesFile: 'path/to/stage/file',
      appName: 'My App (STAGE)',
      package: 'stage.myapp'
    },
    case 'prod': return {
      servicesFile: 'path/to/prod/file',
      appName: 'My App',
      package: 'com.myapp'
    }
  }
})()

export default {
  expo: {
    name: ambientSettings.appName,
    ....
  },
  android: {
    package: ambientSettings.package,
    googleServicesFile: ambientSettings.servicesFile
  },
  ios: {
    bundleIdentifier: ambientSettings.package,
    googleServicesFile: ambientSettings.servicesFile
  }
}
```

OBS: If you change packageName/bundleIdentifier you'll need to do a [clean prebuild](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/prebuild/#clean) after each switch, if you don't you'll have some erros.

As I said before, `eas.json` is used to provide in-app environment vars, so if you need different API URLs in your app you can just:

```
"build": {
  "development": {
    "distribution": "internal",
    "android": {
      "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
    },
    "env": {
      "API_URL": "https://mydevapi.com/"
    }
  },
  "uat": {
    "env": {
      "API_URL": "https://myapi.com/"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this only provides env vars to standalone builds, if you need variables in dev mode (running in expo go mode) you'll need to create a `.env` file and add `import 'dotenv/config'` at top of `app.config.js`.

Hope this helps you.